# When should a port 9040 used for?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, port, dns-zone

A firewall rule for my web app ( python) is created with allowed protocol tcp:9040. I added my domain and created DNS zones, however I still don't get to see my app when I type my domain in the address bar. I have to type my "external ip address:9040" in order to see my app. Is this standard use of firewall for launching an interactive web app? I also read port 9040 is vulnerable. According to speedguide.net: "Trojan.Mitglieder.R (07.01.2005) - trojan with backdoor capabilities. It runs a SOCKS4 proxy server and periodically contacts websites with information about the compromised computer.Attempts to open a back door on port 9040/tcp. Might also initiate a SMTP spam relay server on port 25/tcp."

Thanks.

Comment: Surely, you could look this up for yourself, in the IANA [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml). Ports 9027-9049 are unassigned

Comment: Thank you Ron. This is done by my programmer. Can I change this setting by myself? is there a simple solution or should I hire someone else to change this setting?

Comment: You are confused about things. Unless you have reason to suspect you have a compromised host on your network, you shouldn't worry much about it. Every open port is a vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect your browser to know what port to connect to unless you tell it? If you are using an `http` URL, your browser will connect to port 80. If you're using an `https` URL, your browser will connect to port 443. For any other port, you need to tell it what port to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

> A firewall rule for my web app ( python) is created with allowed protocol tcp:9040. I added my domain and created DNS zones, however I still don't get to see my app when I type my domain in the address bar. I have to type my "external ip address:9040" in order to see my app. Is this standard use of firewall for launching an interactive web app?

This has nothing to do with your firewall. If this is a "web" app that you access via a web browser than the typical configuration would be to run the web app/site on port 80 and to connect to the app via port 80, which is the standard port for the HTTP protocol, which is the protocol used by web browsers. If the programmer configured the web app/website to run on port 9040 then you need to connect to it on port 9040 in your browser by specifying the port number. If you don't want to have to do this then have the programmer configure the app to run on port 80.

Comment: Thank you Joeqwerty. It will be cumbersome for users to remember specifying the port number and I certainly don't like that.